# How to export sas data with danish decimals

Tags: excel, format, export, sas, decimal

I Work daily in SAS. When I export data via proc export or using the "send to Excel" button in SAS EG the number values appear in US decimals (38.329362374). But I want the format to be with Danish decimals (38,329362374).
The way I come around this problem now is to correct the . with a , manually in Excel!

Comment: If you want to use a format that uses the comma try [`NUMXw.d`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000199379.htm). Depending on your output method try one of the approached detailed [here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/316-2013.pdf) or [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/18/406.html). Or to change the excel default see [here](http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-in-excel-2010/)

Comment: Thanks. It was just the answer I was looking for: NUMXw.d

Comment: We typically use COMMAX17.2 for monetary values

Answer (score 0):

this is the format to use NUMXw.d
Use this for future reference 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001263753.htm

it has all the SAS data type!